# Can a PSU, if not sufficient, stop a gpu from posting to the monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

***-I'll Put my PC specs at the bottom-***

Okay, I recently started having a slight heating problem with my stock heatsink for my FX-8350 so I upgraded to a Corsair H80i-GT water loop. When I did I also disassembled my computer to clean it out beforehand, per my usual routine when installing anything hardware related.

After installing everything and getting it situated in my case, for some reason my GPU wouldn't output to my screen. The monitor would recognize something had been plugged in but would say "No Signal" yet I could tell my PC was actually booting up on the other hand as all my custom fan speeds would start. I tried practically everything except a different GPU as I didn't have one on hand. I ended up getting a hold of one(an old EVGA 8600GT) and it worked perfectly fine.

Now I'm trying to figure out if my low power supply could have caused the issue. Also if upgrading my psu to a 850W is worth it and may fix the issue, mind you I can take it back within 30days and get my money back, or if I should upgrade my gpu. Which honestly I would love to not have to upgrade my gpu yet lol.

***Here are my specs:***
Component   Estimated Wattage

**AMD FX-8350** 4.0GHz 8-Core Processor *15W - 125W*

**Corsair H80i** GT 70.7 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler  *10W - 15W*

**Asus M5A97 R2.0** ATX AM3+ Motherboard    *17W - 70W*

**Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB** (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory  *9W - 9W*

**Western Digital AV-25 250GB** 2.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive    *3W - 15W*

**Western Digital BLACK SERIES 1TB**3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive    *4W - 20W*

**Sapphire Radeon R9 280X** 3GB Vapor-X Video Card  *62W - 250W*

**Total:    120W - 504W**

Plus a random 4GB stick of DDR4-1600 Memory

*My PSU is a TR2-500W Thermaltake*

Answer (score 0):

Low wattage from a power supply would more likely shutdown the entire computer and not just the Graphics Card, as it would create a power deficiency for all systems, and BIOSes are not smart enough to make the call of shutting down one service if the power received is too low. While I would recommend upgrading your Power Supply Unit, this should not be the current problem. However to test this, you could remove all but what is needed (Main Hard Drive, one stick of RAM) to see if it is a power problem.

The card might not have been inserted all the way, or properly seated when reinstalled.

Your Windows (I am assume) System could have fumbled with the drivers, I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling the graphics drivers and try again.

And if you didn't wear a static strap while removing and clean pieces of hardware it is possible you have damaged your Radeon. This also seems like the most likely answer to your problem. I would try to find another computer to test your Radeon in. If it still refuses to work, your card has been damaged, and is no longer usable.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I have tried all of that, and yes I am running windows. I also always make sure I am grounded also I am in my basement when I work on this so I'm also on a concrete floor for less static. 
Also the problem did not start untill I installed a water loop, which I'm pretty sure is what is pushing my over my wattage limit. I can't exactly remove that as I don't have thermal paste to put back on the normal heatsink atm.

I guess I'll be trying out if a power supply is what I need, as the graphics card itself powers on and when doing so I hear the fans start up as well as I could hear windows start.

Comment: @Will When I said all that was needed, I implied the processor and any cooling systems. Sorry for the confusion. You just need to drop the max possible power draw to below 500 Watts.